# Find all Bluetooth Devices within range of the phone

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I know that I can discover new devices with `BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()`
`IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)` and `BroadcastReceiver`.

And get all paired Bluetooth Devices via `BluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()`.

But if I pair a device I don't know if it's reachable or not.

Is there a way to get all devices within a reach of phone? I don't even need `BluetoothDevice` Objects, I won't connect with them, I just want their addresses.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the bonded devices from the array/list of the devices found.
Something like this:

```
if (device.bondState != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) { 
       mDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.name + "\n" + device.address)
}
```

Comment: It's not quite what I wanted. The only devices that I can discover with `BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()` are the ones that aren't bonded. I need a way to also discover the bonded ones in reach of a phone.

Comment: When you call startDiscovery you'll get both new and bonded devices. From doc: `Find devices

Using the BluetoothAdapter, you can find remote Bluetooth devices either through device discovery or by querying the list of paired devices.

Device discovery is a scanning procedure that searches the local area for Bluetooth-enabled devices and requests some information about each one.`  And also: `Query paired devices

Before performing device discovery, it's worth querying the set of paired devices to see if the desired device is already known.`

Comment: Well, unfortunately I get only new devices this way. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No problem, if you need help post a bit of your code